# Discord bot - button operate once only node.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js, discord-buttons

Hey everyone I am trying to code a discord bot using node.js allowing the member to submit 1 photo by Slashcommand to be uploaded to the website using MySQL, everything is good they can submit the photo with no problem, for the admin they can check, and Approved or reject the photo by pressing the button in the embed.

The problem is if I receive more than 1 submission and wait for the validation by me! Once I click Approve for example to any photo, all the photos will be approved! I mean single click on Approve button in any photo will approve all other photos and upload them to the database.

here is a copy of the code.

```
module.exports = {
  data: {
    "name": "screenshot",
    "type": 1,
    "description": "Submit your screenshot",
    "options": [
        {
            "name": "nickname",
            "description": "Insert your discord server NickName",
            "type": 3,
            "required": true,
        },
    
            {
            "name": "image",
            "description": "Select your Image from your PC",
            "type": 11,
            "required": true,
        },
    
    
    ]
  },

  async execute(interaction, client){
  const username = interaction.options.getString('nickname'); //get nickname
  const imageurl = interaction.options.getAttachment('image'); //get imageurl

   const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setDescription("``<<<Uploading!>>>``")
  .setColor("#00b0f4")
  .setTimestamp();
  
  const sent = await interaction.reply({
      embeds: [embed],
      fetchReply: true
     // ephemeral: true
    })
    
   const exampleEmbed1 = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setDescription("``<<<Your ScreenShot has been submitted for validation \n\n Thank you!>>>``")
  .setThumbnail(`${imageurl.url}`)
  .setImage(`${imageurl.url}`)
  .setColor("#00b0f4")
  .setTimestamp();
  
  const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
  .addComponents(
          new ButtonBuilder()
          .setCustomId('accept')
          .setLabel('Accept')
          .setEmoji('✅')
          .setStyle('3'),
  
          new ButtonBuilder()
          .setCustomId('reject')
          .setLabel('Reject')
          .setEmoji('❌')
          .setStyle('1'),
  );
     interaction.editReply({ embeds: [exampleEmbed1], components: [row] }).then((msg) => {
     client.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {

     const imgurl = imageurl; //check the image url is the same that I clciked in message..
     if(!interaction.isButton()) return;
     if(interaction.customId == "accept" && imgurl == imageurl){
     
     const memberid = interaction.member.user.id; //get member id
     const messageID = msg.id; //message id

     //insert data in the db
     var sql1 = "INSERT INTO `screenshot` (`name`, `url`, `status`, `messageid`, `memebrid`) VALUES ('"+username+"','"+ imageurl.url+"', '1', '"+ messageID+"', '"+ memberid+"')";
     con.query(sql1, function (err, result){
     if(err) throw err;
     
     //edit reply 
   const exampleEmbed2 = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setDescription("``<<<Your ScreenShot has been Accepted \n\n Thank You! >>>``")
  .setThumbnail(`${imageurl.url}`)
  .setImage(`${imageurl.url}`)
  .setColor("#00b0f4")
  .setTimestamp();
     interaction.reply({ embeds: [exampleEmbed2], fetchReply: true }) //edit reply    
     console.log("screenshot Inserted and approved.");
     })
  
    } 
   
     
     
     if(interaction.customId == "reject"){
     let memberid = interaction.member.user.id; //get member id
     const messageID = msg.id;
     //insert data in the db
     var sql3 = "UPDATE `screenshot` SET `status` = '0' WHERE messageid = '"+messageID+"'";
     con.query(sql3, function (err, result) {
     if (err) throw err;
     
         //edit reply 
   const exampleEmbed3 = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setDescription("``<<<Your ScreenShot has been Rejected \n\n Thank You! >>>``")
  .setThumbnail(`${imageurl.url}`)
  .setImage(`${imageurl.url}`)
  .setColor("#00b0f4")
     .setTimestamp();
     interaction.reply({ embeds: [exampleEmbed3], fetchReply: true }) 
     console.log(result.affectedRows + " record(s) updated");
     });
    
     } 
     });
     
     });

    }
  };
```

I want to validate the screenshot that I click Approve or Reject button only and not all of them will be approved or rejected as now happened to me!
disocrd 14.11

Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track but you're missing a [`messageComponentCollector`](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-message-component-collector) check it out!

I tested this code and removed the query for a testing purposes, you can just add it back, I left a comments there.

```js
module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("screenshot")
    .setDescription("...")
    .addStringOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("nickname")
        .setDescription("something")
        .setMinLength(3)
        .setMaxLength(350)
        .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addAttachmentOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("image")
        .setDescription("..")
        .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addBooleanOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("secret")
        .setDescription("Whether or not the uploading should be ephemeral/secret.")
    ),

  async execute(interaction) {
    const username = interaction.options.getString("nickname"); //get nickname
    const imageurl = interaction.options.getAttachment("image"); //get imageurl

    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setDescription("``<<<Uploading!>>>``")
      .setColor("#00b0f4")
      .setTimestamp();

    await interaction.reply({
      embeds: [embed],
      fetchReply: true,
      // ephemeral: true
    });

    const exampleEmbed1 = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setDescription(
        "``<<<Your ScreenShot has been submitted for validation \n\n Thank you!>>>``"
      )
      .setThumbnail(`${imageurl.url}`)
      .setImage(`${imageurl.url}`)
      .setColor("#00b0f4")
      .setTimestamp();

    const row = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
      new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId("accept")
        .setLabel("Accept")
        .setEmoji("✅")
        .setStyle("3"),

      new ButtonBuilder()
        .setCustomId("reject")
        .setLabel("Reject")
        .setEmoji("❌")
        .setStyle("1")
    );

    interaction.editReply({ embeds: [exampleEmbed1], components: [row] });

    /* NOTE: This what was missing for you
     * FYI: You can change this to keep only the admin is responsible if it's according to your requirement
     */
    // Filter the message to only listen to the user who sent the command
    const filter = (m) => console.log(m.author.id, interaction.user.id);
    // Collect Button Clicks
    const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector(
      filter,
      {
        max: 1,
        timer: 15000,
      }
    );
    // Listen for Clicks on the interaction
    collector.on("collect", async (i) => {
      console.log(i); // for debugging only.
      // If Accept Button is Clicked
      if (i.customId === "accept") {
        // You can do your query here.
        const exampleEmbed2 = new EmbedBuilder()
          .setDescription("``<<<Your ScreenShot has been accepted!>>>``")
          .setThumbnail(`${imageurl.url}`)
          .setImage(`${imageurl.url}`)
          .setColor("#00b0f4")
          .setTimestamp();
        i.update({ embeds: [exampleEmbed2], components: [] });
      }
      // If Reject Button is Clicked
      if (i.customId === "reject") {
        const exampleEmbed3 = new EmbedBuilder()
          .setDescription("``<<<Your ScreenShot has been rejected!>>>``")
          .setThumbnail(`${imageurl.url}`)
          .setImage(`${imageurl.url}`)
          .setColor("#00b0f4")
          .setTimestamp();
        i.update({ embeds: [exampleEmbed3], components: [] });
      }
    });
    // End the listener after the time limit
    collector.on("end", (collected) => {
      console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
    });
  },
};
```

Comment: Thank you, brother, your code worked perfectly, just comment when I try to submit a different photo 2 times [simulate got 2 requests from different users] and click one of the accept buttons the SQL query will upload both images even for the second one. and got error in the logs `DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction` `rawError: { message: 'Unknown interaction', code: 10062 },`  and how to allow admin to accept only or to see the button